# Cannot generate Entity from existing Oracle DB

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.3

Following symfony's documentation to create entities from exiting database,I get an error when running the first command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle yml
```

The error is:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
  Warning: file_put_contents(C:\WebApp\src\AppBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/"user".orm.yml): failed to open stream: Invalid argument
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like User is a reserved word within Oracle databases, so when I created the table, Oracle created a table named "user" with double quotes. So when trying to generate the entity, doctrine cannot find the table user and found an invalid argument "user"  with double quotes in it. The way I solved the problem is by using another name other than user.

Hope this helps someone on the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle yml
```

change to

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import AppBundle yml --force
```

more details:

The doctrine:mapping:import command imports mapping information
  from an existing database:

`php app/console doctrine:mapping:import "MyCustomBundle" xml`

You can also optionally specify which entity manager to import from with the
  --em option:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import "MyCustomBundle" xml --em=default
```

If you don't want to map every entity that can be found in the database, use the
  --filter option. It will try to match the targeted mapped entity with the
  provided pattern string.

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import "MyCustomBundle" xml --filter=MyMatchedEntity
```

Use the --force option, if you want to override existing mapping files:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import "MyCustomBundle" xml --force
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that did not solved the problem.